# Scala : exclude some Dates

Tags: scala, date

I have a list of dates that i want to ignore :

```
 private val excludeDates = List(
              new DateTime("2015-07-17"),
               new DateTime("2015-07-20"),
               new DateTime("2015-07-23")
              )
```

But i always need to display four dates excluding my black Dates list and the weekends. So far with the following code, my counter is increased when i hit an ignored date and it make sens. So how i can jump to the next date until i hit 4 dates not in my black list and my Weekends ? Maybe with a while, but i dont know how to add it in my scala code :

```
1 to 4  map { endDate.minusDays(_)} diff excludeDates filter {
              _.getDayOfWeek() match {
                         case DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY |       DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY => false
                case _ => true
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `Stream` :

```
val blacklist = excludeDates.toSet

Stream.from(1)
      .map(endDate.minusDays(_))
      .filter(dt => ! blacklist.contains(dt))
      .take(4)
      .toList
```

Comment: Hi Peter. What about if i want to exclude the weekend as i just added in my question ? thanks

Comment: @user708683 just change the filter function, or add another filter in the chain. BTW `.filter(dt => ! blacklist.contains(dt))` can be simplified to `.filterNot(blacklist)`.

Comment: I added another filter in the chain but the .filterNot(blacklist) throw an error : type mismatch; found : List[org.joda.time.DateTime] required: org.joda.time.DateTime => Boolean.

Comment: `filterNot(blacklist)` only works when you use a `Set` instead of a `List`

Answer (score 1):

In a quick and rough way I would do it like this

```
val upperLimit = 4 + excludeDates.length

(1 to upperLimit).map( endDate.minusDays ).filter( d => !excludeDates.contains(d) ).take(4)
```

In short you go from the end date backward at max the number of dates you need plus the size of the excluded dates, then you filter the sequence checking if the date is not the excluded list and finally you pick only the dates you need with .take( n )

Hope it helps :)